# How to retrieve documents from a specific folder in SharePoint using GraphServiceClient?

Tags: java, sharepoint, graphserviceclient

I need to retrieve the metadata of all documents in a specific folder in our corporate SharePoint. I use GraphServiceClient for it. I have already created this client adding clientId, clientSecret, and tenantId  but I can't  find the right way to get necessary documents

My sharePoint link to these documents looks like
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/CompanyName/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?ga=1&id=%2Fsites%2FCompany%2DName%2Fshared%20Documents%2FCompany%20Data

I found next way to do it

```
DriveItemCollectionPage driveItems = graphClient.sites(siteId).drives(driveId).root().children().buildRequest().get();
```

But it doesn't work for me.
I have never worked with this lib before, so any help will be very helpful